# Tables: adding content next rows in the in-between rows space

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a table like this:

[image: Example table]

I'd like to have an element between every row. It will be a button to add a row inbetween those rows. Similar to like how Msft Word does it:

[image: How Msft Word does it]

Rowspan won't cut it here, because rowspan will span rows 1 & 2, 3 & 4 but not 2 & 3.

Code for the basic table: https://jsfiddle.net/hs3sz5bh/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>foo row 1</td>
        <td rowspan="2" >+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xxx row 3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" >+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>yyy row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is how I'd like it to look like:

[image: Final result]

Thanks,

Comment: Provide your code please, CSS and HTML

Comment: Added the basic HTML code. I don't think what I'm asking is even possible with HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will work specific to the HTML table you provided but  it will also give you an idea to figure it out if you have different table.

I have added `id` to some cells, and then applied style to each of it.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#cell1 {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

#cell2, #cell1{
  border-bottom: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 11px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  padding-left: 2px;
  
  
}

#cell3{
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>foo row 1</td>
        <td id="cell1">+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar row 2</td>
        <td id="cell2">+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xxx row 3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" id="cell3">+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>yyy row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's the same like I already have. I'd like it to look like this: http://imgur.com/w9L0G0W

Comment: There's still one "+" missing, the one between row 2 and 3.

Comment: Well yeah that's the point of this question, I don't know how to get that "+" between row 2 and 3.

Comment: @RedShift I believe, this is what you are looking for . Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by adding another `table` inside `td` with having only three rows and three cells.

See the following code:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="border:0;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Something here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Something here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Something here</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hs3sz5bh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Needs some fine tuning but using HTML5's [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute we can use the [`:focus` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) in conjuction with the [`:after` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to achieve the following:

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0 4px;
}
tbody tr:focus {
  outline: none;
}
tbody tr:focus * {
  border-bottom: 5px  double black;
}
tbody tr:focus:after {
  content: '+';
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(0.75rem);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holidays</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr contenteditable='true'>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable='true'>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable='true'>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

For the 'new row' buttons to always be visible you can remove the `contenteditable` attribute and the `:focus` part of the css like so:

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0 4px;
}
tbody tr * {
  border-bottom: 5px  double black;
}
tbody tr:after {
  content: '+';
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(0.75rem);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holidays</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Money</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You better read the question, understand it and then vote-down other answers.

Comment: @MaihanNijat You pretty much took their code and posted it as an answer => It's not useful. Mine inserts an element after every row like they wants no reason for the down vote.

Comment: I had enough comments with him/her and understood his question. S/he is not asking what you done. you better see the screenshot he posted for me in my answers comment. Here it is: http://imgur.com/w9L0G0W

Comment: @MaihanNijat Ah thank you for that. I assumed they want the exact same behaviour as Microsoft Word which is why you have to focus on the row to view the button, I've now added an alternative wherein you do not need to focus to see the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use edit this code to achieve somewhat the same result

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
        var ename = $("#ename").val();
        var eid = $("#eid").val();
        var desc = $("#desc").val();

        szTr = "<tr><td>";
        szTr = szTr + ename + "</td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td>" + eid + "</td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td>" + desc  + "</td>";
        if(i%2==0) szTr = szTr + "<td rowspan='2'>+</td>";
        i++;
        szTr = szTr + "</tr>";
        $('#display').append(szTr);

    });


    $('#display').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });

});



</script>
</head>
<body>

Name:<input type="text" id="ename" value="Name"/><br />
Id: <input type="text" id="eid" value="new_id"/><br />
Des <input type="text" id="desc" value="description"/><br />
 <input type="button" value="Generate" id="btnGenerate">

<div id="dvTable">
<table id="display">
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```